# Webscraping soccer data returns nothing

Tags: r, rvest

I would like to scrape the match result table from the website https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/247/Tournaments/36/Seasons/5967/Stages/15737/Fixtures/International-FIFA-World-Cup-2018

I m using rvest package with following code:

```
library(rvest)

url.tournament <- "https://www.whoscored.com/Regions/247/Tournaments/36/Seasons/5967/Stages/15737/Fixtures/International-FIFA-World-Cup-2018"
df.tournament <- read_html(url.tournament) %>%
                  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="tournament-fixture-wrapper"]') %>%
                  html_nodes("table")
                  html_table()
```

while no element is extracted.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the website’s source code you can see that the table doesn’t actually exist in the HTML source — it’s dynamically generated using JavaScript. That’s why your XPath query returns an empty `<div>`.

You consequently can’t rely on {rvest} in this case, you need to use a dynamic scraper such as [{RSelenium}](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium), which can interpret JavaScript.

Comment: I tried several version of R with installation error: package ‘RSelenium’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)

Comment: @useR You need to follow the installation instructions in the link I gave you, since the package was recently removed from CRAN due to an upstream problem. You’ll also need to first install the [{wdman} dependency](https://github.com/johndharrison/wdman) using the instructions given on its page.